# How do I verify AWS Cognito Cookies in my backend?

Tags: authentication, cookies, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

### Context

I have an authenticated frontend talking a backend using the `Authorization` header to pass through a bearer token. The token comes from extracting the `idToken` in our React frontend. In our backend I extract this Bearer token and verify it successfully.

### Switching to cookie auth

I'd like to switch over to cookie auth, so that multiple pages on our domain can all be authenticated together, and to remove token handling code from our JS. I can set the cookieStorage parameter when configuring auth: https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/tools/libraries/configure-categories/#scoped-configuration

However this gives me quite cryptic cookie names (obfuscated):

```
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.1pko4kjgrn0c9m7c**********.google_11790661*************.refreshToken
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.1pko4kjgrn0c9m7c**********.LastAuthUser
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.1pko4kjgrn0c9m7c**********.google_11790661*************.clockDrift
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.1pko4kjgrn0c9m7c**********.google_11790661*************.accessToken
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.1pko4kjgrn0c9m7c**********.google_11790661*************.idToken
```

Note these are just the names of the cookies, the values are the JWTs I expect.

The question is - how do I extract these cookies? My first thought is to use a Regex to find the first cookie named `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider\..*\.idToken` - but surely that's not right!

I've tried searching for examples online, however most recommend setting the `Authorization` header from JS, as we currently do.